# how can I generate json from respond_to method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, respond-to

If I have a block of code like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end
```

How do I add something like

```
format.json
```

Any tips, pointers, ideas gladly welcomed...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's just like the other formats except that you use `render :json` instead.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
  format.json { render :json => @post }
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy - I just figured it out by reading the guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

But you got me there faster!

Answer (score 10):

or you can handle it as javascript

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :json { :only => :name }.to_json }
end
```

then you just access your action with ".js" in the end.

Comment: @Oberon Dude, for what it's worth, I've seen `format.js` a lot more than I have seen `format.json`.

Comment: i didn't check. Normally by the default route, :controller/:action.:format any format is possible, but i don't know if all browsers are able to understand json mime-type..